# Derived template class can't find move constructor for base template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17

I have a pretty large class which is reduced to a minimum failing example below:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Base {
public:
  Base(std::vector<T> &&other) : map{other} {}

private:
  const std::vector<T> map;
};

template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
  Derived(std::vector<T> &&other) : Base<T>{other} {}
};

int main() {
  Derived<double>(std::vector<double>{1,2,3});
}
```

When I run this, I get

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:13:37: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Base<double>'
  Derived(std::vector<T> &&other) : Base<T>{other} {}
                                    ^      ~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:3: note: in instantiation of member function 'Derived<double>::Derived' requested here
  Derived<double>(std::vector<double>{1,2,3});
  ^
main.cpp:3:29: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<double>' to 'const Base<double>' for 1st argument
template <typename T> class Base {
                            ^
main.cpp:3:29: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<double>' to 'Base<double>' for 1st argument
template <typename T> class Base {
                            ^
main.cpp:5:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<double>' to 'std::vector<double> &&' for 1st argument
  Base(std::vector<T> &&other) : map{other} {}
  ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't understand why this is giving me a compilation error. I expect `Base<T>{other}` on line 13 to call the constructor on line 5 since I am passing in `other` which is declared in `Derived`'s constructor argument to be an rvalue (`std::vector<T> && other`). However, the compiler says that it is an lvalue (`std::vector<double>`).

Comment: `Base(std::vector<T> &&other) : map{std::move(other)} {}` will probably be more in-line with what is intended.

Comment: That works too. I was just curious why the compiler seems to remove the rvalue. Is there something in the standard that says this behavior is to be expected?

Comment: If it has a name (like... `other`) then it isn't a rvalue unless you "cast" it to be such using `std::move`.  `void Foo(Bar&&)` is requesting an rvalue, `Foo(std::move(bar))` is granting permission to use it as an rvalue, but it's not until `m_bar = std::move(bar);` that the move actually happens within the Foo routine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since I am passing in other which is declared in Derived's constructor argument to be an rvalue (std::vector && other)

Actually, in the scope of `Derived(std::vector<T> &&other)`, `other` is an lvalue, with a type that is rvalue reference. This is a common point of confusion. Behold the mighty [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue):

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin or std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference**, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

You'll want to explicitly cast `other` to rvalue via `std::move()` in `Derived`'s constructor:

```
template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
  Derived(std::vector<T> &&other) : Base<T>{std::move(other)} {}
};
```